# How to autorun files and scripts in Ubuntu when inserting a USB stick like autorun.inf in Windows?

Tags: autorun

Is there a way to execute a specific script or open a file with a particular program when inserting a USB stick on Ubuntu like the `autorun.inf` file in Windows ? If not, is there another way ?

**EDIT:**
According to the answer I got I have created a file in the *USB root folder* named `autorun` with the above contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
xdg-open myText.txt
```

I have also created a file named `autorun.inf` with the above contents:

```
[autorun]
icon=icon.ico
```

The `autorun.inf` file specifies the *USB icon*.
From the above autorun files only the `autorun.inf` seems to work. The `autorun` script file, when executed it displays the above message.

[image: autorun error message]

Am I doing something wrong or there are some more parameters to be configured in order to run the *script* ?

**P.S:** The files ***myText.txt*** and ***icon.ico*** are placed in the *USB root folder*.

Moreover, the `autorun` and `autorun.inf` file mode bits have been set to 755, using :

```
cd /path/to/usbFolder
chmod 755 autorun
chmod 755 autorun.inf
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open `System Settings` > `Details` > `Removable Media` and set `Software` to `Run Software`

[image: Removable Media]

Your USB Stick must be formatted with a native Linux filesystem like **EXT4**.

Create a shell script with the name `autorun` (or `autorun.sh`, doesn't matter) on your USB Stick and make it executable with `chmod 755 autorun`.

Next time you insert your USB Stick, Ubuntu will notify you about the autorun and ask if you would like to execute this.

[image: Ask before autorun]

To automatically open a document you can use `xdg-open`

```
#!/bin/sh
xdg-open myDocument.odt
```

This will open `myDocument.odt` with the default application for this mime-type. So it will work the same with all other files, too.

To have a custom icon for your USB Stick you can create a `autorun.inf` file with following content

```
[autorun]
icon=icon.png
```

and place your icon as `icon.png` on the Stick.

---

`autorun.inf` on Ubuntu support this commands (take a look at [autorun.inf on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf)):

```
[autorun]
icon=iconfilename[,index]
label=text

[Content]
MusicFiles=yes|no
PictureFiles=yes|no
VideoFiles=yes|no

[ExclusiveContentPaths]
/pictures
/music
more music/special

[IgnoreContentPaths]
/pictures
/music
more music/special
```

Comment: I tried this and when I click on run, I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/p87hpQQ.png) message. Also, is there a way to insert the icon property somewhere in the script or I should create an autorun.inf with contents
`[autorun]`
`icon=icon.ico`
?

Comment: Your script must start with `#!/bin/sh`. Sorry if this was irritating. The line above was just to show the content of the file `autorun`.

Comment: The [error message](http://i.imgur.com/p87hpQQ.png) was displayed while the script contents where only the shell declaration and the command. I did not append the `cat` command on the top. I also tried to open `gedit` but the same error message appeared.
Also, if autorun.inf is supported on Ubuntu, could it also open a script apart from setting the usb icon ?

Comment: Please post your full script (edit your Question). No, `autorun.inf` can not run a script (`open=...` doesn't work).

Comment: Can you please post any other properties of the `autorun.inf` that are supported by Ubuntu if any ?

Comment: Did you make the script executeable with `chmod 755 autorun`? Everything else looks good and does work in here without problems.

Comment: I have set the mode bits of `autorun` and `autorun.inf` to 755 and still the same error message appears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25412/discussion-between-germar-and-pgmank).

Comment: Assuming that the value of `Software` is `Run Software` under `System Settings` > `Details` > `Removable Media` - would it still prompt and **ask** you whether you would like to run the software? 
That prompt should appear only when the value of `Software` is `Ask what to do`, doesn't it? 
In other words: I think that having the value of `Run Software` for `Software` should run the software without any questions or prompts.

Comment: That would be very insecure as it would start programms from every unknown device which could have bin prepared to attack you. I wouldn't recomment doing that.

Comment: @Germar Indeed, but in your case it is set to `Run Software` .. as can be seen in the image. So in your case it should execute the software w/o asking..

Comment: More of a note to self: On my Mint Mate 18.1, that settings dialog can be reached under the name "File Management Preferences"