# Autorun Exterminator type alternatives for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-recommendation, malware, autorun

`Autorun Exterminator` is a tool available for Windows that blocks virus-infected pen drives from automatically executing viruses through `autorun.inf`. Though most of the viruses encountered are `.exe`'s and won't execute by default on a Linux machine, still is there any other software available for Ubuntu that can block viruses from automatically executing from a pen drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu comes with autorun blocking straight from the get-go.

Navigate to **System Settings** > **Details** (near the bottom) > **Removable Media**.

From there, select the dropdown next to Software. To disable autoruns, just set that value to `Do Nothing`:

[image: Do Nothing]

Your system will no longer autorun anything that it sees on a USB stick. It's also worth noting, however, that even leaving this option on `Run Software` isn't exactly dangerous. The system will prompt you before running anything first:

[image]

<sup>Sourced partially from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/642524/208574) on AskUbuntu</sup>