# command line open any file of specific extensions

Tags: boot, scripts

I'm trying to set up a simple pc that basically boots, plays a training video that's saved in the base directory of the flash drive plugged into the pc, and that's it.

currently, I have a logon script set to run

```
sleep 5; totem --fullscreen /media/(username)/*asterisk*/*asterisk*.mp4
```

(specified where I placed asterisks because formatting turns them into italics)

which is just setup to wait a few seconds after boot to allow the pc to recognize the flash drive, then opens any `.mp4` file located in any flash drive.

Is there any way to set this to open any video from multiple filetypes? I.E, open any `.MP4/.MWV/` etc? (filetypes just for example - I'm not sure exactly what types they may end up using)

Comment: use `xdg-open` or `gnome-open` - personally xdg-open is probably best, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-to-properly-and-easy-configure-xdg-open-without-any-enviroment

Comment: I'm no expert, so I could be very wrong, but what I'm trying to do is make the script run regardeless of what they plug into it, so if one time they plug in a usb with a .mp4, it'll run the video, OR, if they plug in a usb with a .wmv, it'll still run without changing the script at all. It looks like xdg-open just sets a preferred application - am I wrong and it can let me open whatever filetype I need?

Comment: `xdg-open /path/to/file` will open the file in question with the default media player. Yes you can set thee defaults as well. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/642511/how-to-autorun-files-and-scripts-in-ubuntu-when-inserting-a-usb-stick-like-autor

Comment: but how does that open a file with a varying file type? I need the script to be able to open anything, regardless of if the user supplies a .mp4 / .avi / .mov etc

Comment: `xdg-open /fpath/to/file.*`