# How to run autorun script without prompt when inserting USB stick on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, usb, scripts, autorun

I am going to run an autorun script when inserting a USB stick.
So I followed the steps in [How to autorun files and scripts in Ubuntu when inserting a USB stick like autorun.inf in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642511/how-to-autorun-files-and-scripts-in-ubuntu-when-inserting-a-usb-stick-like-autor)
Once I inserted the USB stick, the following dialog appears.

[image]

I do NOT want that this dialog appears.
Is there any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For general usage - No. Only with modifications on Host system.

Comment: Actually, this design is also a reason why Linux in general doesn't have a virus problem. A lot of Windows viruses propagate through hidden autorun.inf files in USB flash disks.

Comment: "A lot of Windows viruses propagate through hidden autorun.inf files in USB flash disks" - It has been disabled from Windows Vista (15 years ago).

Comment: Ubuntu now has same mechanism as actual Windows versions - autorun by prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can achieve what I think you want to, is with a rubber ducky, bush bunny, TinyDuck or DigiSpark which are actually seen as keyboards so the "autorun thing" is not a problem.